# Pandas new column based on row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
    Item    SW_test HW_test QA_test
0   PC      Pass    Pass    Pass
1   Laptop  Fail    Fail    Pass
2   Mouse   Pass    Pass    Fail
```

I want to create a final column which will give `Pass` if all tests were pass (not case sensitive) and `Fail` if one or more are fail.

```
    Item    SW_test HW_test QA_test Final
0   PC      Pass    Pass    Pass    Pass
1   Laptop  Fail    Fail    Pass    Fail
2   Mouse   Pass    Pass    Fail    Fail
```

How can I create `df['Final']` in pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `eq` with `all`:

```
df['Final'] = df.iloc[:,1:].eq('Pass').all(1)
#If case sensitive you can use
df['Final'] = df.iloc[:,1:].isin(['Pass','pass']).all(1)
#or
df['Final'] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().eq('pass')).all(1)
#or
df['Final'] = df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(str.lower).eq('pass').all(1)
```

Also instead of mapping again True/False using map, you can use `np.where`:

```
df['Final'] = np.where(df['Final'], 'Pass', 'Fail')
```

Comment: almost close to what i need. two things missing:
- the result should be Pass/Fail. i can accomplish that using map
- the formula only looks for Pass and when it's pass then it gives False. In my question i asked for non-case sensitive. is there a way that can be achieved?

Comment: @AdnanHadi Please check the update. Also Accept and upvote if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
cols = ['SW_test', 'HW_test', 'QA_test']
df['Final'] = df[cols].eq('Pass').all(1)
```

```
    Item    SW_test HW_test QA_test Final
0   PC      Pass    Pass    Pass    Pass
1   Laptop  Fail    Fail    Pass    Fail
2   Mouse   Pass    Pass    Fail    Fail
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply lambda function to check where the condition holds and then can replace the true/false value with whatever you want.
For example:

```
#create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Pass','Pass'], 'b':['Pass','Fail']})


    a       b
0   Pass    Pass
1   Pass    Fail
```

Create a new column where the condition holds

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.a=='Pass' and  row.b=='Pass', axis=1)


    a       b       c
0   Pass    Pass    True
1   Pass    Fail    False
```

Replace the true/false values with what you want to display

```
df['c'] = df['c'].map({ True: 'Pass', False: 'Fail'})


    a       b       c
0   Pass    Pass    Pass
1   Pass    Fail    Fail
```

Comment: I would advise against using apply for such row like operations. The process will be very slow. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Learnt something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# set column to "Pass" initially
df["Final"] = "Pass"

# set "Fail" rows
df.loc[(
    (df.loc[:, ["SW_test", "HW_test", "QA_test"]] == "Fail") | 
    (df.loc[:, ["SW_test", "HW_test", "QA_test"]] == "fail")
  ).any(axis = 1), "Final"] = "Fail"
```